# Save tikz image and use away from latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, png

I need to create and save latex drawing so i can use there else where.

Im using the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,domain=-2:20]
\begin{axis}[
height = 11.7cm,
width = 15cm,
  axis lines=middle,
  grid=major,
  xmin=-2,
  xmax=10,
  ymin=-2,
  ymax=20,
   y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
  xlabel=$y$,
  ylabel=$x$,
  xtick={-2,-1,0,...,14},
  ytick={-2,0,...,20},
  tick style={very thick},
  legend style={
  at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
  anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
]
\addplot[black,thick,samples=1] {0};
\draw[color=red, smooth] plot (\x,\x*\x-8*\x+16) node[above left] {$y = 3$};
\draw (4,1.5) node[anchor=north]{(4,0)};
\draw (1.2,16) node[anchor=east]{(0,16)};
\draw (7,8)  node[anchor=west]{$y=x^2-8x+16$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and i want to save the image it creates as a png. I need to create multiple of these with differences to each image. So i need to create all the images with the exact scale and size so doing a screenshot of the page is not good enough.

From the comments I have developed the code including the preamble from my original document.

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}


\usepackage{xlop}

\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2em}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}

%need for table solutions
\usepackage{xcolor}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\color{red}}
\setlength\fillinlinelength{1cm}
\setlength\answerclearance{0.5ex}

\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand{\sinth}{\sin(\theta)}
\newcommand{\costh}{\cos(\theta)}
\newcommand{\tanth}{\tan(\theta)}
\newcommand{\secth}{\sec(\theta)}
\newcommand{\cosecth}{\cosec(\theta)}
\newcommand{\coshth}{\cosh(\theta)}
\newcommand{\sinhth}{\sinh(\theta)}
\newcommand{\tanhth}{\tanh(\theta)}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sininv}{sin^{-1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cosinv}{cos^{-1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\taninv}{tan^{-1}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]





\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:20, range=-2:10]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  grid=major,
  xmin=-2,
  xmax=10,
  ymin=-2,
  ymax=20,
   y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
  xlabel=$y$,
  ylabel=$x$,
  xtick={-2,-1,0,...,14},
  ytick={-2,0,...,20},
  tick style={very thick},
  legend style={
  at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
  anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
]
\addplot[black,thick,samples=1] {0};
\draw[color=red, smooth] plot (\x,\x*\x-8*\x+16) node[above left] {$y = 3$};
\draw (4,1.5) node[anchor=north]{(4,0)};
\draw (1.2,16) node[anchor=east]{(0,16)};
\draw (7,8)  node[anchor=west]{$y=x^2-8x+16$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

This creates my graph but not in the centre of the page and the graph goes over the page.

[image]

Using the code given below for the equation when it works perfectly. However if i try and do another graph it goes over the page.
[image]

Comment: Just compile it as a standalone document?

Comment: wouldnt that create a A4 page? I want it to be the size of the graph

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Id you use `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` this will produce a pdf of the size of the tikz graph. If you use the `convert` options of `standalone` appropriately, you can create automatically a png of the same page size.

Comment: I dont understand how to do what you are trying to say

Comment: Marmot's solution generates a pdf file with your diagram. You can use another tool to convert the pdf into another format, like jpg or png. This has nothing to do with latex directly. Examples for tools are ghostscript or ImageMagick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be happy to remove this but if I compile

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,domain=-2:20]
\begin{axis}[
height = 11.7cm,
width = 15cm,
  axis lines=middle,
  grid=major,
  xmin=-2,
  xmax=10,
  ymin=-2,
  ymax=20,
   y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
  xlabel=$y$,
  ylabel=$x$,
  xtick={-2,-1,0,...,14},
  ytick={-2,0,...,20},
  tick style={very thick},
  legend style={
  at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
  anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
]
\addplot[black,thick,samples=1] {0};
\draw[color=red, smooth] plot (\x,\x*\x-8*\x+16) node[above left] {$y = 3$};
\draw (4,1.5) node[anchor=north]{(4,0)};
\draw (1.2,16) node[anchor=east]{(0,16)};
\draw (7,8)  node[anchor=west]{$y=x^2-8x+16$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex -shell-escape` I get a png file of the right size.

Thanks for adding a preamble. Unfortunately, your code throws errors and, related to it, the preamble is by far not minimal. After stripping off all things that are not related to the `tikzpicture` one arrives at

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:20, range=-2:10]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  grid=major,
  xmin=-2,
  xmax=10,
  ymin=-2,
  ymax=20,
   y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.05)},anchor=north},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,.5)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
  xlabel=$y$,
  ylabel=$x$,
  xtick={-2,-1,0,...,14},
  ytick={-2,0,...,20},
  tick style={very thick},
  legend style={
  at={(rel axis cs:0,1)},
  anchor=north west,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,fill=gray!10}
]
\addplot[black,thick,samples=1] {0};
\draw[color=red, smooth] plot (\x,\x*\x-8*\x+16) node[above left] {$y = 3$};
\draw (4,1.5) node[anchor=north]{(4,0)};
\draw (1.2,16) node[anchor=east]{(0,16)};
\draw (7,8)  node[anchor=west]{$y=x^2-8x+16$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

which produces, when compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape` this very png file:

[image]

**EDIT**: Type fixed, `pgflatex` -> `pdflatex`, thanks to quark67!

Comment: that is getting closer to what im looking for so thank you however its not drawing the graph correctly

Comment: @JettieBaker I think marmot used your code directly, just adding the preamble and `document` environment, so the output is as you specified it. That said, expect for the fact that the node with `$y = 3$` is clipped away as it's far outside the axis boundaries, I don't immediately see what is wrong with the output, you might have to be more specific.

Comment: @marmot Are we talking about the same node? I was referring to the one in `\draw[color=red, smooth] plot (\x,\x*\x-8*\x+16) node[above left] {$y = 3$};`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, this one is indeed not there. (But this has nothing to do with the conversion but with the fact that pgfplots clips it, I think. In fact, if I add `clip=false` to the axis options the node will be there, together with a curve that overshoots the axis by a large factor.)

Comment: No certainly nothing to do with the conversion, I was just speculating about what Jettie thought was wrong with the diagram.

Comment: Just copying and pasting the code its not creating the graph correctly for some reason. The curve in the code is correct but for some reason its just not plotting the right thing

Comment: @JettieBaker If the output of the above is different from the output you expect, this is most likely due to some directives you have in your document. You do not provide us with this preamble. If you want to find out what is going on, please provide us with a full MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled.

Comment: i still doesnt produce what i want. its will only make a pdf and not a image

Comment: @JettieBaker Well, unfortunately your code throws errors. I stripped off parts of your code that are not needed and/or cause errors, and posted the code and result in my answer. And yes, when I compile the file with `pdflatex -shell-escape`, it does produce a png on my machine.

Comment: +1: Good solution. I do not understand the discussion of the OP though.

Comment: Almost there. I just dont know who to make it a picture from it. Im using overleaf and when i compile it and download its a pdf

Comment: @JettieBaker You can convert pdf's to png with convert, which comes with gimp AFAIK.